# How to switch years to appear in columns when using groupby in a time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series that looks something like these

```
fechas= pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', end='2020-12-01', freq='H'))
data=pd.Series(range(len(fechas)))
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':fechas, 'Data':data})
```

What I need to do is the sum of every day and group by year, what I did and works is

```
df['year']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
df['month']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['day']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day
df.groupby(['year','month','day'])['Data'].sum().reset_index()
```

But what I need is to have the years in the columns  to look something like this

```
res=pd.DataFrame(columns=['dd-mm','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':fechas, 'Data':data})
df = df.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Date"]).date).sum()
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df["dd-mm"] = df.index.strftime("%d-%m")
output = pd.DataFrame(index=df["dd-mm"].unique())
for yr in range(2015, 2021):
    temp = df[df.index.year==yr]
    temp = temp.set_index("dd-mm")
    output[yr] = temp
output = output.reset_index() #if you want to have dd-mm as a column instead of the index
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I also make it work with a pivot table using `df.pivot_table(index=['day', 'month'], columns='year', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()`

Comment: Indeed, that would also work! :) And perhaps looks better also !